# Print Invoice button is not working (displays blank page) in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am working on Magento ver. 1.7.0.2, and whene i try to print any of my invoices, on the backend, i got a white/empty page. Please help me to sort out this matter.

Answer (score 4):

If I guess you are using php 5.4 on your server

This an incompatibility issue between PHP Version 5.4.4 and zend Framwork .

Fixed it by change in this function  lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php.

change

```
abstract public function __construct();
```

to

```
abstract public function __construct($filePath);
```